# Issue with setting heights jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to set heights to two elements with jQuery...
[Link to example](http://testing.lolnode.com/HND_dexter_marks_barber/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(document).width(),
        windowHeight = $(document).height(),
        fadeSpeed = 'slow';

    var aboutOffset = $('div.about').offset().top;

    $('div.head').height(windowHeight);
    $('div.nav').fadeIn(fadeSpeed, function() {
        $('div.head > div.title').fadeIn(fadeSpeed, function() {
            $('div.head > img').fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
        });
    });
    $('div.head > img').on('click', function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: windowHeight +'px'
        }, "slow");
        console.log('image - true');
    });

    $('div.about').height(windowHeight);

    //nav
    $('div.nav > li').on('click', function() {

    });
    //resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        windowWidth = $(document).width();
        windowHeight = $(document).height();

        $('div.head').height(windowHeight);
        $('div.about').height(windowHeight);
    });
});
```

The issue that is currently happening is that when the browser/webpage resizes it then doubles the current height, rather than setting it to the new height. Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

`document` != `window`, your `document` (as representation of highest node of a page) includes both `.head` and `.about`, so it doesn't give you a screen height, but a height of all rendered elements of the page.

```
...
$(window).resize(function() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $('div.head').height(windowHeight);
    $('div.about').height(windowHeight);
});
```

btw you can do the same without using `jquery` at all, just add to your `css`:

```
.head, .about {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```